# Awk: print last n occurrences of paragraphs matching pattern

Tags: text-processing, awk

I use the command `awk -v RS= '/index/' longfile > dataIwant` to save to a file `dataIwant` the paragraphs of `longfile` with data according to the following structure:

```
 index   value       count 
      1     -32.4613      1.00000
      2     -20.5946      1.00000
      3     -13.3573      1.00000
      4     -13.2064      1.00000
      5     -13.2064      0.00000


 other stuff


 index   value       count 
      1     -31.4613      1.00000
      2     -19.5946      1.00000
      3     -12.3573      1.00000
      4     -12.2064      1.00000
      5     -12.2064      0.00000
 

 still a lot of other stuff


 index   value       count 
      1     -33.4613      1.00000
      2     -21.5946      1.00000
      3     -15.3573      1.00000
      4     -15.2064      0.00000
      5     -15.2064      0.00000


 again a lot of other stuff (and so on many times)
```

How to save to file only the last n (ex 2) occurrences of the tables "index, value, count" rather than all of them?

Expected output:

```
 index   value       count 
      1     -31.4613      1.00000
      2     -19.5946      1.00000
      3     -12.3573      1.00000
      4     -12.2064      1.00000
      5     -12.2064      0.00000
 index   value       count 
      1     -33.4613      1.00000
      2     -21.5946      1.00000
      3     -15.3573      1.00000
      4     -15.2064      0.00000
      5     -15.2064      0.00000
```

Comment: So there are only 2 occurrences in the example, right?

Comment: The last 2 occurences of **what** ?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk sorry, I just avoided copying and pasting. Actually the pattern with the table "index, value, count" is repeated many times, not only 2, and I want to get the last two tables saved to a file.

Comment: Add clear sample input and **expected output** by editing your original post (not as a comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save matching paragraphs in an array and in the `END` block print the last `n` elements e.g. for `n=3`:

```
awk  -v n=3 -v RS= '/index/{z[i++]=$0};END{for (j=i-n; j<=i; j++) print z[j]}' in > out
```

Comment: Don't save every record and then discard most of them as that wastes memory which could be a problem if the input is huge, just save the last 2 at every step by using an index of `(++i)%n` instead of `++i`.

Comment: @EdMorton - fair enough but then, the order of matching paragraphs will not be preserved in the output unless the total number (of matches) is a multiple of `n`,  right?

Comment: No, I added an answer to show how to do it.

Comment: @EdMorton - ah, OK, thanks for teaching me stuff! 

Answer (score 1):

Just keep a rolling buffer of the last n records and print them in the END:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS=""; ORS="\n\n" }
/index/ { recs[(++c)%n] = $0 }
END {
    for ( i=1; i<=n; i++ ) {
        print recs[(++c)%n]
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -v n=2 -f tst.awk file
 index   value       count
      1     -31.4613      1.00000
      2     -19.5946      1.00000
      3     -12.3573      1.00000
      4     -12.2064      1.00000
      5     -12.2064      0.00000


 index   value       count
      1     -33.4613      1.00000
      2     -21.5946      1.00000
      3     -15.3573      1.00000
      4     -15.2064      0.00000
      5     -15.2064      0.00000
```